# How to write and read informations from the database in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I can't write and read informations from the database in Drupal 8.

In Drupal 7 it looked like this:

```
# save & update
variable_set('variable', 'value');

# get
variable_get('test', false);
```

I know that in Drupal 8 it looks completely different but enerything I tried 
does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read data from a configuration object use `\Drupal::config()->get('system.site')->get('name')`.

To set data to a configuration object you first need to load the editable configuration entity, then set the data and finally save it.

```
$site_settings = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.site');
$site_settings->set('name', 'Foo site');
$site_settings->save();
```

To save custom configuration to the database, create a configuration yaml file:

**modules/MODULE_NAME/config/install/custom.configuration.yml**

```
custom-variable: 'hello world'
```

You should also probide a schema file for your configurations:

**modules/MODULE_NAME/config/schema/custom.configuration.schema.yml**

```
custom-variable:
  type: 'string'
  label: 'Custom variable'
  description: 'A custom variable to store information in the database'
```

Comment: Works great with one change. GET should look like this `$system = \Drupal::config('system.site');` `$value = $system->get('variable');`

Comment: @WalterWhite get() is used for imutable config only. getEditable() is for mutable config.